# Number of substrings - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations

Say you have two strings $A = a$ and $B = b$. Now, how do I come up with an expression that gives me the number of substrings of $C = abaa$ that contain atleast one occurrence of both $A$ and $B$?

The number of substrings of $C$ that contain both $A$ and $B$ are:

$ab$

$ba$

$baa$

$aba$

$abaa$

How do I model this in combinatorics?

Comment: What about $aba$?  Also:  if $a,b$ are themselves strings might there not be others?  Suppose, say, that $b$ is itself a substring of $a$...then $a$ would already work.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have updated the question. If $b$ is already a substring of $a$, it would pose no problem. Only the number of substrings will get increased. For ex: $A = ab$ and $B = b$ and $C = abba$ then there would be $ab, abb, abba$ substrings

Comment: What is your definition of a substring? To be precise, do you consider $ac$ to be a substring of $abc$?

Comment: No. A substring is a contiguous sequence of characters from the original string. $ac$ is a _subsequence_ of $abc$.